# value must exists in both tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I've got two tables:

```
create table customer
(
cust_id
cust_name
)

create table customerphone
(
customerphone_phone,
cust_id,
)
```

cust_id must exists in both tables, how can i check this?

Comment: Did you consider a Foreign Key?

Comment: No i don't, don't know how to explain easily but every customer must have a customerphone

Comment: How about putting customerphone on the customer table instead of in its own table? Or can customers have more than one phone number? You can't really enforce that the record has to exist in both tables, since you can't insert into two tables at the same time (transactions notwithstanding).

Comment: It cannot be a requirement that it must be present in both tables - any DML statement (INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE/MERGE) only affects a single table at a time. So there *must* be times when a value is present in one table but not in the other. Which way around do you prefer for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This cannot be done with Declarative Referential Integrity (DRI) alone.  Adding a foreign key constraint is only part of the solution.  You will also need to need to wrap a transaction and business logic around the inserts to the 2 tables.  I recommend doing this in a stored procedure so that it operates as an atomic operation from the perspective of the application.

```
Begin Transaction
  Logic around inserting a Customer
  Logic around inserting CustomerPhone row
If the newly added Customer has a CustomerPhone
    Commit Transaction
Else
    Rollback Transaction
```

Answer (score 2):

Make `cust_id` a primary key on the table `customer`.

Then make `cust_id` a foreign key on the table `customerphone`, which points back to `cust_id` on `customer`.

Then you can only add rows to `customerphone` if the `cust_id` already exists in `customer`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **cust_id** from **customer** as PRIMARY KEY, and use a FOREIGN KEY to restrict the **cust_id** in **customerphone**.

You can guide yourself using this manual:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175464(v=sql.105).aspx